# Вывести список сотрудников с названием департамента и именем руководителя

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

вывести к колонке начальников их подчененых которые повязаны к одному департаменту. Каким способом можно это сделать. Я пробовал разные join-ы но не получалось вывести колонку оставшихся сотрудников к их начальникам. Я новичок в sql простите пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
SELECT 
    employee.name,
    employee.chief_id,
    department.name,
    department_id
FROM
    employee
        INNER JOIN
    department ON department.id = employee.chief_id
```

Comment: @Akina Мне надо будет добавить перченую e1 в Select и дальше сделать так как ты написал?

Comment: @Akina SELECT 
    e1.*
FROM
    employee e1
        LEFT JOIN
    employee e2 on e1.chief_id = e2.id

У меня всех закидывает в одну колонку но не разделяет на вторую где бы видно было департамент/начальник/сотрудник

Comment: @Akina могли бы вы объяснить метод подробнее пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT e1.name AS employee_name,
       e2.name AS chief_name,
       department.name AS department_name
FROM employee AS e1
JOIN employee AS e2 ON e1.chief_id = e2.id
JOIN department ON e1.department_id = department.id
```